# Bootstrap Modal with Select2 Focus issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I have select2 selects on bootstrap 3 modal.

For all three components the code is as follows

```
   $('#primaryModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {

            $(".icdLookup").select2({
               .../
             }):
};
```

The problem I have am having is in the picture below. If I make a selection on a select2 and focus out to another input the focus will still remain on the select2 box.

[image: enter image here]

Comment: is your problem the focus class being applied to multiple elements.. not really sure what that is showing specifically.

Comment: If I don't make any selection in the select2 box and I go to another field then it will remain open.

Comment: possibly related to this https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/1436

Comment: I fixed by overwriting 

    $.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this problem by applying the following fix (just put it in your JS code):

```
//fix modal force focus
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {
  var that = this;
  $(document).on('focusin.modal', function (e) {
     if ($(e.target).hasClass('select2-input')) {
        return true;
     }

     if (that.$element[0] !== e.target && !that.$element.has(e.target).length) {
        that.$element.focus();
     }
  });
};
```